# How to call public void in Fragment from same Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want in the Actionbar button click change my Fragment page textView Text.

I am using Activity and Fragment. in this Activity

How to call public void in Fragment from same Activity? Thank all~

Code

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
        }

        MaterialTabHost tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setType(MaterialTabHost.Type.FullScreenWidth);

        tabHost.addTab("one page");
        tabHost.addTab("two page");

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(tabHost);

        tabHost.setOnTabChangeListener(new MaterialTabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(int position) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.name:
                //in here call  public void setItem, set the textView Text.
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        TextView textView;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ge_layout, container, false);

            textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            return rootView;
        }

        public void setItem() {
            textView.setText("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not creating the optionsmenu inside the fragment?

Comment: can you post your adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have reference to that fragment, which you can obtain through FragmentManager:

If you add your fragment to the layout in xml file using the `<fragment>` tag, define its id:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/placeholder_fragment"
    android:name="com.your.package.PlaceholderFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In your activity:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.placeholder_fragment);
placeholderFragment.setItem();
```

Other way to add fragment is to do it programatically:

```
private static final String TAG_PLACEHOLDER = "placeholder";

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
placeholderFragment = (DataLoaderFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_PLACEHOLDER);
if (placeholderFragment == null) {
    placeholderFragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(sectionNumber);
    fm.beginTransaction().add(placeholderFragment, TAG_PLACEHOLDER).commit();
}
// you have the reference to fragment from calling newInstance(sectionNumber) or findFragmentByTag, so you can execute the method:
placeholderFragment.setItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice should be to create the options menu and its functionality inside the fragment.

But if there is some reason why you set it in the activity, then you could use something like this:

```
((PlaceholderFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName())).setItem();
```

Depending on how you added the fragment to the backstack.